# iOS7 receipt contains CFBundleVersion instead of CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store

I am trying to convert my paid app to freemium using the newly available receipts on iOS7, and while I'm there I am also doing receipt validation.

I am a bit confused because the receipts are returning the CFBundleVersion for both the current and original version not the CFBundleShortVersionString against which we should verify the receipt according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2).

Did anyone else experience this? Should I allow receipt validation to succeed by checking against CFBundleVersion, or is this something temporary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that iOS receipts do not use the CFBundleShortVersionString for the orignial version and current version, but the CFBundleVersion. See details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW2). This is a difference from the Mac receipt, so anyone using Mac receipt validation code for iOS should be aware of this.